# (Over) Contribution between two employers for the Roth 401k case to maximize matching

Tags: united-states, roth-401k, employer-match, excess-contribution

I know there are a few question about changing employers during a calendar year and trying to maximize company match between the two for 401k plans. I've read through them and I think I understand that, in general, if the plan allows for a corrective distribution, and you get this done before April 15th of the following year for the current year, then no harm no foul.

I am wondering if there are any differences with a Roth 401k situation. Especially since a regular 401k plan considers it an "excess deferral" due to the tax advantage, but in a Roth situation, this is post tax, so I'm unsure how this works.

Scenario:

Employer 1:

- employed from Jan 1, to Jun 3.
- Retirement plan: Enrolled in Roth 401k plan
- Contribution YTD: ~$15,600 (I was aggressive since I was unsure if this contract position would be renewed or converted to a direct hire position at the firm I was working at.)
- Employer match: **No match**

Employer 2

- employed Jun 6 to present
- Retirement plan: plan to enroll in Roth 401k plan
- Contribution: To be determined!
- Employer match: 6%
- Other: company also allows an extra $10,000 for after tax contributions to plan
- Pay period: biweekly paycheck

Questions:

- Should I overcontribute to get the maximum matching?
- Are there any tax considerations? (I assume no?)
- Any other considerations?

Comment: Are you aware that employer match is always pre-tax (so never Roth)?

Comment: Are you saying that if i go the Roth way i would miss out on matching? This was something i intended to ask our benefits department…

Comment: No; I am saying _the employer matching would be non-Roth_ either way.

Comment: Sure, but the employer match wouldn't count against the 20,500 limit. But I'm asking about if I get the full match, and **my** contribution exceeds the limit, then what?

Answer (score 1):

I was in this situation a number of years ago though my over contribution was accidental.

I asked the first employer to correct the over contribution, but they refused and said I needed to have the second employer do it.

Not a guarantee that you'll have the same outcome but I think it is likely.